# Create library using Webpack

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I would like to build an ES6 library using Webpack.

I generate a file using a webpack.config.json like that:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: 'src/Main.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'MyLib.min.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  }
};
```

And my Main.js:

```
import {Car} from './Car.js';
import {House} from './House.js';
import {Character} from './Character.js';
```

The problem:
When I want to instantiate something in my index.html (inside `<script>` after including "MyLib.min.js"), I've got an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Character is not defined
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my configuration, did I miss something?

Comment: It should be `webpack.config.js`, not `json`. Could that be it? Also, unless you're using webpack v2, you need to include [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader).

Comment: It sounds like `./Character.js` doesn't have a named export `Character`. Please review ES6 modules and verify that you use the correct import statement.

Comment: Also, be aware that webpack 1.x doesn't support es6 modules by default. Your configuration cannot recognize these imports at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you expect `Character` on the global scope. You can do that inside `Main.js` by simply adding `window.Character = Character`.